# "Error: unable to open port" in installing Blackberry application on mobile

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have created a BB application and want to install on mobile.
It is working perfectly on emulator but getting problem when I am installing on mobile.

I am using javaloader.exe for installing it on mobile.

```
Connecting to device...debug: HRESULT error during Open: 80040154
Error: unable to open port
```

How to solve this error?
Same `.cod` file I can install from my other PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually that error means you need to install Blackberry Desktop Manager. Do you have that installed?

Comment: yes i have installed but it is giving same error. i can install it from other pc which is not having bb desktop manager. isn't there any way to solve this error???

Comment: Can you install the app via desktop manager instead? Not sure what the problem is otherwise. Could maybe be a problem with the versions of the JDE and Desktop Manager you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sepcify the connection type:

JavaLoader.exe -u load xyz.cod

-u = USB

Or install the USB drivers:

https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=A8BAA56554F96369AB93E4F3BB068C22

Info from:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Error-unable-to-connect-to-device-in-blackberry-using-javaloader/td-p/275908